# Post to php server with a string which combined chinese and english

Tags: ios, objective-c

In case needs , I need to post six parameters to php server, the last two parameters which are **pic_country** and **pic_city** are chinese characters!

If I start to post this string to php server via xcode , it worked fine with **pic_country** but **pic_city** .....,the **pic_city** character can't be retrive by php server. Php server seems not recongize after this string `pic_country=%@`

I had been used .html file to post same content via browser for examining my .php file, my .php file worked great on both **pic_country** and **pic_city** , so I think the problem is not my php server.

Below is my code , can someone help me!! Thank very much!

```
NSString *postString =
[NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"user_id=%@&pic_datetime=%@&pic_longitude=%f&pic_latitude=%f&pic_country=%@&pic_city=%@",
 use_id,pic_datetime,longitude,latitude,country,city];

NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[postString UTF8String] length:postString.length];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:PublishPictureInfo_URL]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];

NSError *error;

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"responseString = %@",responseString);
```